# Contraction Mapping with uniform metric...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

**Question**: Let $\mathcal{X} = C([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ (the space of real-valued continuous functions on the closed interval $[0, 1]$) with the uniform metric $d(f, g) = \max_{x \in [0, 1]} |f(x) - g(x)|$. Define $T: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}$ by

$$T(f(x)) = 1 + \int_0^x tf(t) dt, 0 \leq x \leq 1.$$

1. Prove that $T$ is a contraction map.
2. Let $f_0(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$. Set $f_{k + 1}(x) = T(f_k(x))$, for all $k \geq 0$. Find explicitly $f_n(x)$ for $n = 1, 2, 3$. Then prove that the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges in $(\mathcal{X}, d)$ to $f(x) = e^{x^2/2}$, for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

**Answer**:

1. I was able to prove that the mapping $T$ is a contraction map with Lipschitz constant 1/2.
2. This is where I am confused. Let me present my work first.

It follows that

$$f_1(x) = T(1) = 1 + \int_0^x t \cdot 1 dt = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2},$$

$$f_2(x) = T(1 + x^2/2) = 1 + \int_0^x t\cdot\bigg(1 + \frac{x^2}{2}\bigg)dt = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4},$$

and

$$f_3(x) = T(1 + x^2/2 + x^4/4) = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^6}{8}.$$

In general, we then have that

$$f_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \bigg(\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg)^k.$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1 - \big(\frac{x^2}{2}\big)} = f(x).$$

So, did I mess up or is this problem asking the wrong question?

Comment: For $f_{2}(x)$, the antiderivative of
$$
{t^3  \over  2}
$$
is
$$
{t^4 \over 8},
$$
no?

Comment: That was a typo on my end. The $t^2$ should be an $x^2$, right?

Comment: Oh...I see what you are saying now. I am being dumb, I was doing $f(x)$ instead of $f(t)$. Thank you.

Comment: If $f_{1}(x) = 1 + x^2 /2 $, then
$$
f_{1}(t) = 1 + t^2 /2,
$$
and so
$$
t f_{1}(t) = t + t^3/2.
$$

Comment: You are being human.  Humans make mistakes.:)

Comment: The limit function does indeed seem to be $\frac1{1-x^2/2}$ and not $e^{x^2/2}$ though.